# Custom Colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I'm trying to create a custom colorbar, but the colorscale looks completely different to what I'm defining - 
[image]

The color should be going from brown -> white -> blue, There should be 9 categories.

My code is attached below:

```
plot = np.clip(plot,40,250)

bounds = [0, 40, 60, 80, 100, 125, 150, 200, 250, 300]
rgblist = [(51,25,0), (102,51,0), (153,76,0), (239,159,80), (255, 255, 255),
       (153,204,255), (51,153,255), (0,102,204), (2,2,128)]
clist = [[c/255 for  c in rgb] for rgb in rgblist]
cmap = colors.ListedColormap(clist)
norm = colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)


cs = m.contourf(X,Y,plot,bounds, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
cbar = m.colorbar(cs, ticks=[20,50,70,90,112.5,137.5,175,225,275])
cbar.set_ticklabels(['<40','40-60', '60-80', '80-100', '100-125', '125-150', '150-200', '200-250', '>250'])

plt.show()
```

Comment: What is `m`?  What is `colors`?  You don't seem to be giving enough information.

Comment: Sorry, m is the basemap (m = Basemap(projection='merc',resolution='f',llcrnrlat=49,llcrnrlon=-11,urcrnrlat=61,urcrnrlon=3)) and colors is just from the import (from matplotlib import colors    )

Comment: If easier - https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=4A445014A6259A95!153597&authkey=!ANIC53D3ck5-HD8&ithint=file%2cpy

Comment: Are you using Python 2?

Comment: Then I think my answer should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that you are using Python 2.x. In that case, your line

```
clist = [[c/255 for  c in rgb] for rgb in rgblist]
```

is performing integer division, i.e. the result is stored as an integer and all fractional information is lost. In your case, this leads to all divisions except `255/255` resulting in `0`.

To change this, you can either divide by a float by just adding the decimal point:

```
clist = [[c/255. for  c in rgb] for rgb in rgblist]
```

Or you can import the Python 3 division behaviour before the division via

```
from __future__ import division
```

Comment: This works perfect, just a full stop away from it working, lol! Thanks so much.

Comment: No problem. Feel free to accept my answer if it solved your problem.